# Add django class based view to admin site

Tags: django, admin, django-class-based-views

I have created some forms using class based views, now I like to add them to the Django Admin site. I have only found this [link](http://patrick.arminio.info/additional-admin-views/) which describes adding normal views to the Admin site.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Prepare to get downvoted to oblivion. :) Please read [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines on forming detailed, useful questions.

Comment: The topic is actually interesting, but you make it upside down by asking "Nothing"... @PhilippWiesner, suggestion: just implement what you've read in the link.

Comment: So, perhaps this might be your real question ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079979/django-extend-context-of-class-based-view-with-admin-context

Comment: Yes, both questions are linked, because this was my first problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as_view()` method of class-based view returns regular view so you can call it from `ModelAdmin` like this:

```
def review(self, request, id):
    return MyReviewView.as_view()(request, id)
```

Comment: `as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 8):

Let say you have the following class based view:

```
# File: views.py
class MyAwesomeBookView(TemplateView):
    pass
```

To use this view, you have to make it `callable`

```
# File: views.py
awesome_book_view = MyAwesomeBookView.as_view()
```

Once your view is `callable`, you can pretty much treat it like how you treat a *function-based view*.

To link it to the admin urls, you could do something like this:

```
# File: admin.py
@admin.register(Book)
class BookModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^awesome-books/$', 
                self.admin_site.admin_view(awesome_book_view)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
```

Answer (score 6):

For a full integration with Django admin templates, you can pass the model admin as an extra argument to the class based view, then use it to add some sugar to the context:

file admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
from .views import ProcessObjectView

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
        info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^(?P<object_id>.*)/process/$',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(ProcessObjectView.as_view()),
                {'model_admin': self, },
                name="%s_%s_process" % info),
        )
        return my_urls + urls
```

file views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_permission_codename

class ProcessObjectView(UpdateView):

    model = MyModel
    pk_url_kwarg = "object_id"
    fields = [... ]
    template_name = 'admin/backend/mymodel/process_object.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # see http://www.slideshare.net/lincolnloop/customizing-the-django-admin
        model_admin = self.kwargs['model_admin']
        opts = model_admin.model._meta
        admin_site = model_admin.admin_site
        has_perm = self.request.user.has_perm(opts.app_label + '.' + get_permission_codename('change', opts))
        context.update({
            'admin_site': admin_site.name,
            'title': 'Process: ' + str(self.get_object()),
            'opts': opts,
            'app_label': opts.app_label,
            'has_chage_permission': has_perm,
        })

        return context
```

file process_object.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n utils_tags %}

{% block content %}
...
```

Comment: Using `admin_site.each_context(self.request)` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.each_context)) might give you a more comprehensive context.

Comment: This is a pretty complex but very detailed - thus inspiring! - answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the class based view's `as_view` directly, without need of having a variable like `awesome_book_view` as suggested by another answer:

Example:

in `admin.py` I have:

```
class EmailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(EmailAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^send_email/$',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(SendEmailAdminView.as_view())),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

admin.site.register(Email, EmailAdmin)
```

in `views.py` I have:

```
class SendEmailAdminView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        pass

    def post(self, request):
        pass
```

I have removed most of the code for brevity and have kept only relevant part. You can see the full [code here](https://github.com/avinassh/nightreads/tree/master/nightreads/emails).