# Django: Extend context of class based view with Admin context

Tags: python, django

I have a class based view which just displays a list of configurations.

This view is added to the Django Admin site by using the following code:

```
@admin.register(ZbxHostConf)
class ZbxHostConfListViewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    review_template = 'admin/admzbxhostconf_list.html'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(ZbxHostConfListViewAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
                           (r'^zbxhostconflist/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.review)),
                           )
        return my_urls + urls


    def review(self, request):
        return ZbxHostConfListView.as_view()(request)
```

The template extends the `admin/base_site.html` template. I can access the site only after I log in to the Django Admin site. Unfortunately the template cannot access the context data provided by the admin view.

As the Django documentation suggests the context data will be provided directly to the `TemplateResponse` function:

```
  def my_view(self, request):
        # ...
        context = dict(
           # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
           self.admin_site.each_context(request),
           # Anything else you want in the context...
           key=value,
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "sometemplate.html", context)
```

For function-based views there is the possibility of the extra_context argument but class-based views don't provide this argument. I guess I have to modify the get_context_data function but I don't really understand how I can provide the admin context data to the get_context_data function of my class based view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well not directly. I have just added it for the sake of completeness. But if removal will improve the question I will do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not be a correct answer, but I believed you could try something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from django.contrib import admin

class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):    
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(admin.site.each_context(self.request))
        return context
```

Comment: @PhilippWiesner Does it work for you? I haven't run it on my computer. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes it works fine, the admin context data are send along with the normal data from the view. Thank you very much :)